# Save Custom logout url through Apex code

Tags: security, session, logout

In Setup >> Security Controls >> Session Settings >> Logout Page Settings. System Admin can define Logout Page URL. Can we set this via Apex Code or Metadata API ?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_securitysettings.htm

Comment: @identigral this is correct answer. You should post it as full answer.